# Confused about using SpringMVC Vs Java EE project in Netbeans

Tags: spring, netbeans, spring-mvc, java-ee-6

I want to start a my first Java EE project. I have read a lot that springMVC framework is a good choice (never used though)

My earlier experience with java is not much. only some small app development using Netbeans. so I have some experience using Netbeans.

But I see that I can start a Java EE project in Netbeans. so what kind of framework netbeans is using underneath.

PS: My understanding of framework (e.g. SpringMVC) is that you follow rule of framework to configure your app. and then framework take care or linking your View, controller and model. 
so if i am using netbeans, do i need to take care of linking of my MVC by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see that I can start a Java EE project in Netbeans. so what kind of framework netbeans is using underneath.

Hmm... Nothing. NetBeans is just an IDE and let you use whatever framework you want: JSF 2.0, Wicket, Struts 2, Stripes, Spring MVC, your own poison. Of course, one could say that NetBeans promotes (and supports) JSF 2.0 but this doesn't mean you can't use another framework, just add the required libraries to your project.

In any case, Spring MVC is just one options amongst others and is not an absolute requirement to write Java EE applications. Some Java EE applications don't even have a web interface actually. And believe it or not, you can write Java EE application - especially Java EE 6 applications - without Spring :)

Comment: Thanks Pascal, 
but my app would be having a web interface and a desktop client as well ( that the reason i am trying to use netbeans). 
So this means that i have to use a MVC framework?
if i do not choose any framework while creating a project. does this have any disadvantages ?

Comment: Do you *have to* use a MVC framework? Strictly speaking , no. *Should you* use a MVC framework? Yes. And I'm pretty sure that NetBeans will let you add any libraries after the creation of the project.